# Inquiry Regarding Unfamiliar Charges for "Dataplex" in GCP Billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-dataplex

I am currently running queries for aggregations such as GA in GCP's BigQuery. The queries are straightforward, and the data volume is still relatively low, allowing me to perform aggregations within the free tier.

However, I recently noticed charges and billing under the item "Dataplex" in one of my projects. It appears to be incurring charges daily, but I have no knowledge of Dataplex and no recollection of enabling it.

I speculate that it may be related to BigQuery within a specific project, but I am unaware of the setup process and how to disable it.

The "Cloud Dataplex API" is not activated. I would appreciate guidance on how to stop the daily charges for "Dataplex." If you have insights into the setup history or the steps to disable it, please share them with me.

I am using BigQuery.
Is it possible to incur charges related to BigQuery even when the Dataplex API is in a disabled state?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Devatim, Have you checked this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataplex/docs/enable-api#disable), for disabling the dataplex API and its charges ? Let me know if this helps you or not.

Comment: @DhirajSingh The "Cloud Dataplex API" was originally not enabled, and upon reconfirmation, it remains disabled. Despite this, I am still encountering charges under the "Dataplex" item in my billing. I have no recollection of enabling Dataplex and would appreciate guidance on understanding and resolving these unexpected charges.Additionally, lake management, where the loading process does not seem to complete, and nothing is displayed. Is the ongoing loading a potential problem, and how can I address this issue?Your insights and assistance on these matters would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Comment: @DhirajSingh  Thank you. As I don't have a support plan, I'll look into the IssueTracker.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the Data Lineage API enabled.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).